# TypeError in Django with python 2.7

Tags: python, django

Hey, new to Django and needing assistance, when I add my model to the admin interface in Django it appeares fine, but when I try to add or delete an entry in the database I get:

```
TypeError at /admin/Users/user/add/    
  coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

I done a google search and added:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ""
```

To the end of my User model class but with no success. Not sure if I have to enter something into my admin.py? I also have no "add" method in my User class, it also returns nothing else other than the method above.

Thanks for any help!

The User Class:

```
class User(models.Model):
GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
email = models.EmailField()
password = models.CharField(max_length=30)

birth_date = models.DateField()
description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENDER_CHOICES, default = "M")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/photos/")
signupIP = models.IPAddressField()
privateOrPublic = models.BooleanField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return ""
```

And the simple admin.py in /Users/

```
 from Users.models import User
 from django.contrib import admin

 admin.site.register(User)
```

Traceback:

```
 Environment:

 Request Method: POST
 Request URL: http://127.0.0.1/admin/Users/user/add/
 Django Version: 1.2.3
 Python Version: 2.7.0
 Installed Applications:
 ['django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'Users']
 Installed Middleware:
 ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


 Traceback:
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
   100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
   239.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
   76.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
   69.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
   190.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
   21.             return decorator(bound_func)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
   76.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
   17.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in _commit_on_success
   299.                     res = func(*args, **kw)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
   795.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, change=False)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in save_model
   597.         obj.save()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
   434.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
   517.                         for f in meta.local_fields if not isinstance(f, AutoField)]
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
   255.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in save
   91.         name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in generate_filename
   282.         return os.path.join(self.get_directory_name(), self.get_filename(filename))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in get_filename
   279.         return os.path.normpath(self.storage.get_valid_name(os.path.basename(filename)))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in __getattr__
   276.             self._setup()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in _setup
   242.         self._wrapped = get_storage_class()()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in __init__
   133.         self.location = os.path.abspath(location)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py" in abspath
   465.                 path = _getfullpathname(path)

 Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/Users/user/add/
 Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?  Have you customized the User class at all?

Comment: I am not familiar with admin site, but if you change your \__str__ to \__unicode__ is still the same?

Comment: Still the same, think it has something to do with the admin interface rather than my code, not sure tho. And posted more code Ned.

Comment: Post the whole stack track. It will include line numbers. That line is where the error will be. Posting the lines near that will help if you can't get it from that

Comment: Added traceback Daenyth.

Comment: What's your settings MEDIA_ROOT value? Sounds like it's a problem with resolving the full path for the uploaded images.

Comment: Hey Vasil the MEDIA_ROOT is MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "media").replace("\\", "//"),

Comment: @pyBite42: Are you trying to replace a literal `\ ` or two of them? If the latter, use `r'\\'` as otherwise you'll be just replacing one. (also the comment formatter seems to break with backslashes next to  backticks...)

Comment: Thankyou Daentyh that's it, if you want to post that as an answer I would be happy to mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MEDIA_ROOT definition, change your replace to have a raw string, as otherwise you'll be replacing a literal single backslash rather than the two you meant.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), "media").replace(r"\\", "//")
```